# Why do we need to add cordova.js for adding sound/music to app?

Tags: ios, cordova

I've been trying to add sound/music to my phone gap iOS app. But getting "Media not found error". The only difference i see in my code and phone gap documentation is missing java script file. So,could please tell me, what is this "cordova.js" and is it mandatory to add? Thanks in advance!

[Documentation link.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

Cordova.js is the new version of phonegap.js

https://cordova.apache.org/

If you are building an iOS app, you should really read about it, rather than asking here what the documentation says..

in essence cordova/phpgap connects the device's hardware ion/outputs with javascript, so you can use simple javascript to play music, upload/downlaod files, save files, vibrate, etc...

I assume you know , or should know by now, that to use nay functionality, you need to add the appropriate plugins in your cordova project.

Comment: I've basic understanding of how plugins and functionalities are interdependent (and app is working as expected but without sound). So, my question was related to Media not found error..anyways, thanks!

Comment: I was referring to `So,could please tell me, what is this "cordova.js" and is it mandatory to add? Thanks in advance!` , but yes, you need the media plugin + cordova.js library to play the file.